# jQuery: Check username for invalid characters

Tags: jquery, validation

I am using jquery to check for invalid characters. I know this is unsafe but I am also using a PHP check and the jquery is just for instant feedback. What is the string I would use to verify the input. Is it something like `[az-AZ-09]`? Also how do I check the value against that string? Thanks!

Comment: You would use RegEx to compare against what you want and use that. Tell us what you don't want to accept and we'll provide a proper RegEx. Also, why reinvent the wheel, check out this plugin: http://bassistance.de/jquery-plugins/jquery-plugin-validation/ - It has built in formulas for common inputs.

Comment: @SergioTapia I don't want any of these !@#$%^&*()-_+=~`\|[{;:'"/?.>,< or any special characters like œ∑´®†ˆøπåß∂ƒ©˙∆˚. Only characters(upper/lower) and numbers. Thanks sorry for the late response, my phone died so I couldn't respond.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Why not just use a simple regex?

```
var name = ...;
if (name.match(/[a-z0-9]+/i)) {
  ...
}
```

Comment: Thanks! Thats what I was trying to ask but I didn't remember what it was called.

Answer (score 1):

You need to use a regex. It works the same way as PHP

Comment: Oh, I didn't realize it was the same as PHP.

Answer (score 1):

You might want to try javascript owns reg expression methods to check against a pattern, instead of calling a php script and returning what it found. See https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Guide/Regular_Expressions

Answer (score 1):

you can use jquery [validation plugin](https://web.archive.org/web/20201214234222/https://docs.jquery.com/Plugins/Validation) , and to avoid duplication you can just use your php validation code and get instant feedback by sending an ajax request with your username to your php here's a [working example](http://jqueryfordesigners.com/using-ajax-to-validate-forms/) of how to do it  .

Comment: I would prefer to no use a plugin. Thanks anyway.

Answer (score 1):

Good answer given by JaredPar (the accepted answer), but you'd better use `/^[a-zA-Z0-9]+$/` if you don't want 'username#' or 'user name' to pass.

See this [SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9628879/javascript-regex-username-validation)