# javascript regex (username validation)

Tags: javascript, regex

I want to enforce that

1. the input firstname should only contains characters A-Z, a-z, and -
2. the input login name should only contains alphanumeric characters

How do I restrict the two rules in javascript?

Below is my code (jsp) for username regex. But it's not working properly.

```
function validateForm(){
    var nameRegex = /^[a-zA-Z\-]+$/;
    var validfirstUsername = document.frm.firstName.value.match(nameRegex);
    if(validUsername == null){
        alert("Your first name is not valid. Only characters A-Z, a-z and '-' are  acceptable.");
        document.frm.firstName.focus();
        return false;
    }
}
```

Thanks!

Comment: What's the difference between *username* and *login*? Furthermore, what's wrong with what you have (other than inconsistent naming)?

Comment: @JasonMcCreary One is firstname and the other is login name. Using above code, if I use horatio2m as firstname input, the user can still be saved, which is not what I want. I want to validate that the firstname input should only contains a-z,A-Z,and -

Comment: Replace `if(validUsername == null){` with `if(validfirstUsername == null){`.

Comment: @JoshPurvis Yes, you're right. A stupid mistake. Thank you.

Comment: What about firstname like `Hervé` or `François` or `Günter` ...?

Comment: The real problem here is that a user can simply turn off javascript and submit whatever username they want. please validate this on the backend, too.

Comment: @AlexanderCorwin please mention some code or link for validate backend are please provide a crud operation that contain login logout with validation in java

Answer (score 37):

The code you have looks fine, aside from the inconsistent variable reference (see the comment by **Josh Purvis**).

The following regex is fine for your first name spec:

```
var nameRegex = /^[a-zA-Z\-]+$/;
```

Adding digits for your username check is straightforward:

```
var usernameRegex = /^[a-zA-Z0-9]+$/;
```

**Note:** There are many ways to write regular expressions. I've chosen to provide a version that matches what you started with. I encourage you to work through this [Regular Expression Tutorial](http://www.regular-expressions.info/)

Comment: Can I use /[a-zA-Z\-]/ instead of /^[a-zA-Z\-]+$/ ? Why we need to use ^ in front of [a-zA-Z\-]?

Comment: ^ means Matches the starting position within the string

Comment: `^` means the beginning of the string. `$` means the end. If you left off the `^`, for example, `~@*##@horatio` would pass your validation. Likewise for the `$` and the end of the string being checked.

Comment: I would like to point out that this allows 12345 to pass as a valid username. How would you make sure there's at least one letter?

Answer (score 10):

Here's the validation function I came up with, tailor it for your own use-cases:

```js
function isUserNameValid(username) {
  /* 
    Usernames can only have: 
    - Lowercase Letters (a-z) 
    - Numbers (0-9)
    - Dots (.)
    - Underscores (_)
  */
  const res = /^[a-z0-9_\.]+$/.exec(username);
  const valid = !!res;
  return valid;
}
```

Answer (score 8):

Usernames can only use letters, numbers, underscores, and periods.

```
  const onValidUsername = (val) => {
    const usernameRegex = /^[a-z0-9_.]+$/
    return usernameRegex.test(val)
  }
```