# How to check if a text doesn't contains whitespace nor emoji?

Tags: javascript, regex

I would like to write a regex to check if a username is valid. A username is considered valid only if it has no whitespace, no emojis and at is least 3 characters long. What would be the right regex for this?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [javascript regex (username validation)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9628879/javascript-regex-username-validation)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

to get exactly what you mentioned (prevent ONLY emojis and white spaces & check if it is at least 3 characters, you can use this regex check

```
/^[^(\u2700-\u27BF)(\uE000-\uF8FF)\uD83C(\uDC00-\uDFFF)\uD83D(\uDC00-\uDFFF)(\u2011-\u26FF)\uD83E(\uDD10-\uDDFF)\s]{3,}$/g.test(USER_NAME_HERE)
```

However, I'd recommend avoiding these confusing checks as much as possible, and instead of checking if it doesn't match the wrong format, instead, check if it matches the correct format, so you need to define what is the right format first, ( have letters only? letters and numbers? some special characters are allowed?)

for example: assuming the right format is at least 3 characters containing only letters, numbers and '_', you can do this

```
/^[a-zA-Z\d\_]{3,}$/g.test('')
```

which is more clear and readable

Answer (score 0):

Guessing you want front-end (javascript) validation, but regardless, Use regex or a library to check `are all characters letters`

@Oriol has some js regex for this https://stackoverflow.com/a/23476587/6791342

so you could do

```
const REGEX_ALL_LETTERS = /^[a-zA-Z]+$/ ;
...
const isValidUserName = (userName) => {
    return (!!userName
             && userName.length >= 3
             && REGEX_ALL_LETTERS.test(userName) );

 
}
```

`/^[a-zA-Z]+$/.test("aUseRName")` // false

`/^[a-zA-Z]+$/.test("a UseR Name")` // false

Answer (score 0):

```
 const usernamepattern = new RegExp(/^([a-zA-Z]{1})([a-zA-Z\d\.\_-]{1,20})([a-zA-Z\d]{1})$/);
```

this formula says that the first char must be a [letter] then in the middle [letters or dots or _ or - or digits] and the last char must be [letters or digits]

and in the middle part allowable from 1 char to 20 char

if there is any unallowable chars like emojis or even $ , # , @ , or anything
will return false and you can specify it as you like